What is the "data" format in FFmpeg?
There is a format in FFmpeg called "data" and every way I've tried using it causes the Output file does not contain any stream error.
I've tried:
ffmpeg -f data -i in.bin -f data out.bin

And:
ffmpeg -f data -i in.bin out.mp4

And, finally:
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -f data out.mp4

The only offical documentation that exists AFAIK just says "Raw data".
What is this format?

data is for format-agnostic single-stream data, so it can be anything.
You have to explicitly add a map and codec setting in order to copy any stream i.e.
ffmpeg -f data -i in.bin -map 0 -c copy -f data out.bin

or
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -map 0:a:1 -c copy -f data out.bin

